# Combine two tibbles in R using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have 2 tibbles

```
x <- tibble(A = letters[1:4],
            B = letters[5:8])
y <- tibble(A = letters[9:12],
            B = letters[13:16])
```

I'd like to obtain

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  A     B    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a,i   i,m  
2 b,j   j,n  
3 c,k   k,o  
4 d,l   l,p
```

I need a code that does it without hardcoding the column names because I have to work on tibbles that can have from one to many columns. The 2 tibbles will always have the same number of columns and rows. I prefer to avoid for loop if possible.

Thank you,
Marco

Answer (score 3):

One option could be:

```
x %>%
 mutate(across(everything(), ~ paste(., y[[cur_column()]], sep = ",")))

  A     B    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a,i   e,m  
2 b,j   f,n  
3 c,k   g,o  
4 d,l   h,p
```

Comment: I like this because it does not rely on the columns being in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `paste`.

```
z <- as.data.frame(x)
z[] <- paste(unlist(x), unlist(y), sep = ",")
# If you need tibble as output. 
tibble::tibble(z)

# A tibble: 4 × 2
#  A     B    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a,i   e,m  
#2 b,j   f,n  
#3 c,k   g,o  
#4 d,l   h,p
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `purr` to map over the two data.frames as collections of columns

```
purrr::map2_df(x, y, paste, sep=",")
```

Comment: perfection! well done

Comment: FYI, `*_df` functions were superseded in `purrr` 1.0.0 :-/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option that does not rely on `x` and `y` being in the same order:

```
library(purrr)

data.frame(map(set_names(names(x)), ~ paste(x[[.x]], y[[.x]], sep = ",")))
```